# Android - Como obter Extras em um InnerFragment(Fragmento Aninhado)?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Como obter um `Extra` dentro de Fragment aninhado em outro Fragmento?

Tenho um Activity com o seguinte Layout:

```
Activity (que infla um){
  //Aqui a activity infla 3 Fragments para criar um BottomNavigation
  Fragment (que infla um){
    //Em um certo Fragment (uma dos três botões do BottomNavigation, é inflado alguns fragmentos em uma TabLayout
    InnerFragment
  }
}
```

Eu não tenho como enviar um Bundle para o `InnerFragment`, apenas para o Fragment, e segundo a documentação Fragments não devem nunca se comunicar diretamente.

E a abordagem `getActivity().getIntent().getExtra().getInt()` não é apropriada. Visto que faz com que o fragmento não seja reutilizável.

Qual seria a abordagem correta?

Exemplo de layout no Youtube:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]